# Upgrade unlocked package fails due to "Cannot use unfiled-public or user folders in a package"

Tags: unlocked-package, install

I'm trying to install the unlocked package to a sandbox org, where a previous version of it already exists.

I used to have an email template in unfiled public, but I moved it to a public read/write folder. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve it. An email template with the exact same name has been created in the Sandbox in unfiled public, but wasn't part of the unlocked package. After deleting it, I could install the package.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an easy way to determine this immediately, but it may be due to the default upgrade type of Mixed. Try using the Delete mode instead:

```
sfdx force:package:install -p the_package_to_install -t Delete -u myAlias -w 10
```